# Return specific values from several select statements in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery, job-scheduling

Had a problem with a select within a select, to get a specific result, but I managed to get around that problem, only to get stopped with another one.

I have a code that it's something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM   bo 
           WHERE  nmdos LIKE '%preço%' 
                  AND datafinal = Dateadd(day, -6, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()))) 
  EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'SQL Server - 2017', 
    @recipients = 'mail@mail.com', 
    @query = 'select * from bo     where nmdos like %preço%     and datafinal = DATEADD(day, -6, convert(date, GETDATE()))', 
    @subject = 'Encerramento Dossiert', 
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1; 
ELSE 
  PRINT '0'
```

the error I get says this:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

how can I get this to work, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have missed quote in LIKE. Use this like ''%preço%'' insetad of %preço%

Comment: Nop, that didin´t do it :/

Answer (score 0):

You missed quote in @query variable

```
@query = 'select * from bo where nmdos like %preço% and datafinal = DATEADD(day, -6,convert(date, GETDATE()))'
```

You need this

```
@query = 'select * from bo where nmdos like'+' ''%preço%'' ' +'and datafinal = DATEADD(day, -6, convert(date, GETDATE()))'
```

You can see the difference with this query:

```
 DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'select * from bo where nmdos like'+' ''%preço%'' ' +'and datafinal = DATEADD(day, -6, convert(date, GETDATE()))' 

select @query
```

Comment: thank you @alexkidd. i think it's getting real close, now i got a different error:

Incorrect syntax near '+'.

the first one, right next to like'+' ''%preço%''

Comment: try this: 'select * from bo where nmdos like'+' ''%preço%'' ' +'and datafinal = DATEADD(day, -6, convert(date, GETDATE()))'